# Fortran makefile for compiling fixed form and free form files with modules

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77

I'm trying to compile and link mixed format Fortran code for EFDC, a numerical fluid dynamics code made up of 243 .for and .f90 files.  There are two modules that are in two .f90 files.

It's written in serial and I'm using gfortran on Linux.  The main program is in one .for file and the rest are subroutines in fixed and free format.  There aren't any files that have fixed and free together.  I'm having trouble adapting the makefile examples around to my specific case.

I'm trying some of the fixed to free form converters now, but I would like to know how to compile from the makefile only.

I've attached my makefile below.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
# Name of executable
TARGET:= bcsa_efdc.out
# Fortran compiler
FC := gfortran
# Only using maximum optimization Fortran flag
FFLAGS := -O3
# What files to build from
OBJECTS := *.f*
# Process rules
%.o: %.for
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -c -o  $< $@
%.o: %.f90
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -c -o  $< $@
# Compile executable
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you write that Makefile yourself, or was it based on an example Makefile?  I see a number of potential issues, but don't have a copy of the model sources to test this out.  Try this

```
# Name of executable
TARGET:= bcsa_efdc.out
# Fortran compiler
FC := gfortran
# Only using maximum optimization Fortran flag
FFLAGS := -O3
# What files to build from
SOURCES := *.f*
# Create a list of object files from the source files
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.for,%.o,$(patsubst %.f90,%.o,$(SOURCES)))
# Process rules
%.o: %.for
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -o  $< $@
%.o: %.f90
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c -o  $< $@
# Compile executable
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
$(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)
```

The changes from your original Makefile include:

- Put object filenames in $(OBJECTS) instead of source filenames
- Take incorrect dependence on sources/object names in the compile rules
- $(TARGET) properly depends on objects now, not sources and objects are used in building the target rather than recompiling sources.

The `patsubst` line just replaces .f90 and .for with .o for all of the source files.

By default gfortran will compile *.for in fixed-form mode and *.f90 in free-form mode.  If you need to override this, you can use `-ffree-form` and `-ffixed-form` arguments.